# Dungeon Defense's Korean web novel ending?

Tags: dungeon-defense

Like in title what happened at the end of the story?

I heard that it's different from the light novel, where in the web novel everyone have died, is it true?

(I can't read Korean)

Comment: If you were a new user, I'd ask "what have you tried to answer your own question? Have you tried reading the web novel's ending perhaps?" but I know you're not new and I gotta ask what gives man

Comment: I dont read korean so i dont know but i heard it different  then light novel.

Comment: You should absolutely add that into your question to provide evidence of some research or to explain what limits your ability to find the answer.

Comment: its korean, and only [Shalvation](https://shalvationtranslations.wordpress.com/) made it avaliable to english reader so far.. you could ask him regarding the ending, seriously. Also, i'm a bit bugged by the tag - **dungeon _defence_** or **dungeon _defense_**..?

Comment: @BagusTesa I've fixed the tag with [dungeon-defense].